# Camera preview and recording size

Tags: android, video, camera, commonsware-cwac

I am using this library for a video sharing application project and I am using the CameraDemo_layout and I am setting the com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraView dimensions to 320dip in both, height and width. However, the recorded video seems to have the recording with the dimensions of the phone screen which makes it look so wrong. Would you please walk me through the process of setting the video recording to follow the dimensions of the camera viewgroup layout. Thank you.

My Activity:

```
public class RecordingActivity extends Activity implements
```

CameraHostProvider {
    private DemoCameraFragment current=null;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recording);

    current=new DemoCameraFragment();

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, current).commit();


}

@Override
public CameraHost getCameraHost() {
    return(new SimpleCameraHost(this));
}
```

My Fragment:

```
public class DemoCameraFragment extends CameraFragment {
android.hardware.Camera camera;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View content=inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera, container, false);
    CameraView cameraView=(CameraView)content.findViewById(R.id.camera);
    Log.d("daba", "the cameraview attrs: " + cameraView.getHeight() + " -- " + cameraView.getWidth());
    setCameraView(cameraView);


    //      SimpleCameraHost.Builder builder = new SimpleCameraHost.Builder(getActivity());
    //      builder.useFullBleedPreview(false);
    //      
    //      setHost(builder.build());

    final ImageButton record = (ImageButton) content.findViewById(R.id.record);
    final ImageButton next = (ImageButton) content.findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setEnabled(false);
    record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(record.getTag().toString().equals("Hi!")){
                try {
                    record();
                    record.setTag("By!");
                    record.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                    next.setEnabled(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else{
                try {
                    stopRecording();
                    record.setTag("Hi!");
                    record.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
    });


    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isRecording())
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Finish recording first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), VideoSetData.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });

    if(isRecording()){


    }



    return(content);
}
```

}

My Camera.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraView
    android:id="@+id/camera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/cancel" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/right" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/record"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/record"
        android:tag="Hi!" >
    </ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the recorded video seems to have the recording with the dimensions of the phone screen which makes it look so wrong

The resolution of the recording should have nothing to do with the dimensions of the `CameraView`. The resolution of the recording should come from your configuration of [the `MediaRecorder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) using [`setProfile()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setProfile%28android.media.CamcorderProfile%29).

`setProfile()` is used in the `CameraHost` in `configureRecorderProfile()`. The `SimpleCameraHost` uses its own algorithm for choosing a profile; you will need to subclass `SimpleCameraHost` and override `configureRecorderProfile()` to use a different algorithm for choosing a profile.

Comment: It is not about the resolution, I just want to make the camera record only according to the height and width of the @+id/camera layout. I am hope I am not wasting your time here. Thanks.

Comment: @AbdellahBenhammou: The height and width of a video, in pixels, is called the "resolution". You cannot control the resolution of video recording by changing the size of the `CameraView`. You control the resolution of video recording by configuring the `MediaRecorder`. You may not be able to specify an arbitrary resolution, in which case you will need to modify the video after it was taken using `ffmpeg` or something.